# slotToEndPOSIXTime error

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

Firstly, when I attempt to build a repl of week01 what I get is [image: this]

Then when I attempt to use slotToEndPOSIXTime I get [image: this]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!  Everything else works great up until this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s because def :: SlotConfig method is not found.

You have to “import Data.Default” first

Comment: I needed sleep last night and figured it would be a while before anyone answered.  Thank you for being so quick!  THIS WORKED!  Thank you so much!